# Parsley ajax sending post variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

From their official documentation:

```
        Custom ajax validation made simple.
parsley-remote-method="POST" to change default GET call.
parsley-remote-datatype="jsonp" if you make cross domain ajax call and expect jsonp
Parsley will accept these valid returns with a 200 response code: 1, true, { "success": "..." } and assume false otherwise
You can show frontend server-side specific error messages by returning { "error": "your custom message" } or { "message": "your custom message" }
```

However what can i do if i wish to send a variable with the post request?

Comment: i think if you put a name attribute on your input a variable with the same name and the input value will be send with the post request.

Comment: What if i want to send multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a remote validator on the field you will need to put both attributes

```
parsley-remote="http://yoururl.com"
```

and

```
parsley-remote-method="POST"
```

to make the variable submitted in a POST request.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="1" parsley-remote="http://yoururl.com" parsley-remote-method="POST" />
```

then your script at the back-end has to validate the "test" variable and return 200 response with:

```
{ "success": "all good!" }
```

or

```
{ "error": "your custom message" }
```

Comment: Can i send multiple values to the remote destination?

Comment: please example of back-end file with response.

Comment: An update - I was just trying to use the remote validation and the error message wouldn't come up. I had to issue a 400 return code header in order for Parsley to figure out the validation failed. On top of that, returning a JSON object(even with the proper content-type header) with an error property didn't override the default error message. I ended-up adding `data-parsley-remote-message="My field remote validation error message."`. Not sure if this answer is for an older version of Parsley or the API change, or I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Parsley.js, you can use `data-parsley-remote-options` like so:

```
data-parsley-remote-options='{
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "data": {
        "token": "value"
    }
}'
```

Put whatever you need to send as a key/value pair in the `data` object.

More information in [the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#remote-options).