# Parsley custom error message doesn't work

Tags: html, parsley.js

I have the following input field:

```
<input id="name" name="real_name" type="text" placeholder="ie. Your full name or company name" class="form-control input-lg parsley-validated"
   data-required="true" parsley-error-message="Please insert your name" >
```

However, when I press my submit button, I only get the standard `This value is required.` message.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Forgive my unfamiliarity with parsley.js, but what is the expected output? Is this happening even if you submit valid input?

Comment: The input should be Please insert your name

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this attribute instead of `parsley-error-message`:

```
data-parsley-required-message="Please insert your name"
```

It's not a custom error message for custom validator.
You need to override the default 'required' error message with your one.

Comment: could you look at my Ajax question aswell? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391978/parsley-ajax-sending-post-variables

Comment: is `data-parsley-error-message="my message"` only for custom validation ? The documentation says: `Customize a unique global message for the field.` I toought it was working like @MarcRasmussen said. (i have a local and remote validation for VAT validation and the error message is the same)

Comment: @Leto: I tried `data-parsley-error-message` and it works for all error messages for that field. It just becomes the error message for *any* error in that field.

Comment: doesn't work for me i using `bootstrap 4` and `parsley 2.9.1`

Comment: For more recent versions: `data-parsley-required-message`

Comment: I have required and a custom validation for a field but it is taking data-parsley-error-message for both this didn't help me

Answer (score 60):

Try

`data-parsley-required-message="Please insert your name"`

Comment: Or "data-parsley-error-message" for a generalized response.

Comment: Still doesn't work, always "Please fill out this field"

Comment: I think they must have changed the property name or something. This one worked for me with version 2.3.3.

Comment: If you're on later versions, this is the ticket.

Comment: Works for version 2.8.1

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the correct version now. Reference: https://parsleyjs.org/doc/#ui-for-field

Answer (score 1):

For required field validation :

```
data-parsley-required-message="Please enter name"
```

For input pattern validation :

```
data-parsley-pattern-message="Please enter valid name"
```

In short change third word with your validation type.