# How to use ParsleyJS 2.* using javascript and not data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Looking in the docs they only offer examples with data attributes, I need to write a different js file for a form and do something like:

$('#myform').parsley(options);

I want to know the available methods in options, and apply validators to inputs and then print custom messages.

It is possible?

Comment: I think this is similar to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246268/configure-parsley-using-javascript-not-html-data-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the camel case equivalent. See also the [defaults](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html)

```
$('#myform').parsley({errorClass: 'oups'});
```

Some javascript methods are in the [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field), others you have to look in the source.

For example, (see [this on how to add the corresponding validator](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft)):

```
$('#myform').parsley().addConstraint('isMultiple', 42)
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the replay, I'm looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392813/parsley-custom-error-message-doesnt-work but in javascript, I don't see a way in defaults.js do you think is possible?

Comment: http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html#javascript this but in version 2.*

Comment: Edited answer, hope this is better. PRs for documentation more than welcome :-)