# Configure Parsley using Javascript, not html data attributes

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

How do I configure Parsley using javascript, not html data attributes?

The documentation examples show how to configure the Parsley form instance and some global field options using JS, but I want to be able to add and configure all field instances that way too.  I don't want to use the html data attributes.  Is that possible?

I think this question is driving at the same problem, [How to use ParsleyJS 2.* using javascript and not data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971494/how-to-use-parsleyjs-2-using-javascript-and-not-data-attributes), but it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 3):

@kim-prince Hope this helps

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="number" placeholder="Number" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$('#myForm').parsley();
$("#number").parsley().addConstraint('type','number');
$("#number").parsley().addConstraint('minlength',2);
$("#number").parsley().addConstraint('required');
</script>
```

see working codepen:
http://codepen.io/ds0001/pen/QwoRVx?editors=101