# How to configure a Parsley custom remote using javascript, not attributes

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971494/how-to-use-parsleyjs-2-using-javascript-and-not-data-attributes) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246268/configure-parsley-using-javascript-not-html-data-attributes) I can't figure out how to How to configure a Parsley custom remote using Javascript, when binding an individual field.

e.g. I'm trying (simplified):

```
$('#field').parsley({
    remote: true,
    remoteValidator: 'mycustom';
});
```

being the equivalent of [the example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote-custom):

```
<input name="q" type="text" data-parsley-remote data-parsley-remote-validator='mycustom' value="foo" />
```

after I've registered the example remote:

```
window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('mycustom', function (xhr) {
    console.log(this.$element);
    return 404 === xhr.status;
}, '/api/foo');
```

When this executes Parsley does try to process the remote inside the internal remote function:

```
validateString: function validateString(value, url, options, instance) {
```

While the `Parsley.asyncValidators` *does* include the `mycustom` remote OK, the `options` parameter is not the options I would expect (it's the Parsely field itself which has those options as an `options` property). So `options.validator` in this context is null, and so the method picks the default, which isn't configured, and so it errors on `url.indexOf`. Anyway that's probably all irrelevant if I've configured it wrong.

I've looked through the documentation, samples and source code, but cannot figure out how these values are read from the config.

Update: I installed it via bower and am using dist/parsely.min.js. I cannot see the parsely.remote.js (mentioned in the docs) anywhere in the bower build so I presume it's all compiled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the value of the `remote` option needs to be "remote" not `true`.

```
$('#field').parsley({
    remote: 'remote',
    remoteValidator: 'mycustom';
});
```

As there is no attribute value for `data-parsely-remote`, I'd guessed "presence of tag" would evaluate to `true`, not the last word of the dashed attribute.

Comment: PS: To get the options of a parsley field, simply use `$('#field').parsley().options`

Comment: The .options method is garbage-in-garbage-out though. It just returns what I put in.

Comment: Yes. So are attributes. Sorry, I don't see the point, nor the relation with your question

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Posted an answer, OTH.

Comment: I was saying that because the .options method just returns whatever I have set, it doesn't help me to find out what the correct settings are. For example, there is no mention in the documentation about the "remoteValidator" configuration setting - I had to guess it, from the equivalent html attribute. I only found out about the camelcase equivalence from another SO - it's not mentioned in the documentation, so the object literal configuration approach is very hard to use.

Comment: It *is* in the documentation. It's listed as `data-parsley-remote-validator`, which corresponds to `remoteValidator` option, as explained in the "Naming" section.
I read many people complaining about the documentation, I see very few PRs to make it better though :-)

Comment: OK I can see that section. I didn't really glean from that the correspondence between the two ways of providing the configuration, as it's talking about how the data-attributes are converted but I can see that it must work "backwards" too. Re. PRs, when I feel I understand it enough to confidently make a contribution I will try, but currently I don't feel I can add any value.

Comment: Sure. You're not the first to miss the correspondance section though, maybe it should be more explicit, or referenced in many other places, etc...

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `validateString(value, url, options, instance)`, the `options` you will receive are the options of the `remote` validator. This validator is defined with:

```
  requirementType: {
    '': 'string',
    'validator': 'string',
    'reverse': 'boolean',
    'options': 'object'
  },
```

So there will be a `validator` option ('mycustom'), possibly a `reverse` option, and also possible a `options` option.

So you could bind your field with:

```
$('#field').parsley({
    remote: true,
    remoteValidator: 'mycustom',
    hello: 'world',
    remoteOptions: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```

and access `'bar'` within your validator with `options.options.foo` or `instance.options.remoteOptions.foo`, and get `'world'` with `instance.options.hello`.

Comment: I'm not defining `validateString()` - it's inside the Parsley codebase. I was only inspecting there to try to guess what settings to define for the remote by trial an error. I don't want to know about the internals of the library, just the required configuration settings which aren't documented in the object literal format.